# In TypoScript, how to display a 'New' beside a menu item if c1&c2&c3 conditions are fulfilled?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Here is the code in typo3 7.6.27:

```
2.NO {
    after = &nbsp;<span class="nouveau">New</span>
    after.if.value.data = date:U
    after.if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f1
    after.if.value.data = field:f2
    after.if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f1
    after.if.value.data = date:U
    after.if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f2
}
```

Comment: Hey, you cannot combine the `if` statements. I would suggest to use a `userFunc` or handling it via Fluid (if you're using Fluid templates).

Comment: It's better to add more details man.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add multiple conditions into one `if` function in typoscript.
Remember: typoscript will be transfered into a php array before it is being evaluated.

In your example your second condition overwrite the first, and the third overwrites any before.

Typoscript has no build in mechanism for logical operators, so you need workarounds like `userfunc` or cascaded `stdWrap`

So a possible solution might be:

```
2.NO {
    after = &nbsp;<span class="nouveau">New</span>
    after.if.value.data = date:U
    after.if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f1
    after.stdWrap.if.value.data = field:f2
    after.stdWrap.if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f1
    after.stdWrap.stdWrap.if.value.data = date:U
    after.stdWrap.stdWrap.if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f2
}
```

or you use menuprocessors and fluid after you update to a current version of TYPO3, which is very outstanding if you still use TYPO3 7.6.27 which is out of support for two years. (7.6 ELTS is 7.6.40)

---

> In addition to that, if I want to do a else with a similar block of conditions to display "Updated" if it has been updated, is it possible?

There is no `else` in typoscript condition function.
you could use `override` or `ifempty` but in this case I would suggest to use a `COA` in the `after`:

```
2.NO {
   after.cObject = COA
   after.cObject {
       10 = TEXT
       10.value = &nbsp;<span class="nouveau">New</span>
       10 {
           if.value.data = date:U
           if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f1
           stdWrap {
               if.value.data = field:f2
               if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f1
               stdWrap {
                   if.value.data = date:U
                   if.isGreaterThan.data = field:f2
               }
           }
       }
       20 = TEXT
       20.value = &nbsp;<span class="update">Updated</span>
       20 {
           if.value.data = date:U
           if.is???Than.data = field:f1
           stdWrap {
               if.value.data = field:f2
               if.isG???Than.data = field:f1
               stdWrap {
                   if.value.data = date:U
                   if.isG???Than.data = field:f2
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

with appropriate conditions for `20`.

Comment: In addition to that, if I want to do a else with a similar block of conditions to display "Updated"  if it has been updated, is it possible?

Comment: answer enhanced.

Comment: Wow! 2 good answers on 2 questions , it's great! You must have experiment many years with Typo3!

Comment: I work with TYPO3 for some years.  :-) If my answer works for you, you should accept the answer